# Get all children titles of a page as a link to them

Tags: pages, links, title, children

I want to pull all the children titles of certain page and put them as a link.
This is what i got so far:

```
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
                    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

                    // Get the page as an Object
                    $oferta =  get_page_by_title('Oferta');

                    // Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
                    $all_children = get_page_children( $oferta->ID, $all_wp_pages );

                    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $_children, true ) . '</pre>';
```

Now, how can I get page titles from $all_children ?

Answer (score 1):

What you put doesn't make much sense, as it turns a 1 step action, into a 4 step action

Why not just put:

```
$oferta =  get_page_by_title( 'Oferta' );
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $oferta->ID
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you were following [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children). You've followed it pretty much to the letter, but it doesn't do a great job of explaining what is in these objects. Try this:

```
<?php
// Set up the objects needed
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

// Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
$all_children = get_page_children( get_the_ID(), $all_wp_pages );

// echo what we get back from WP to the browser
if(!empty($all_children)){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($all_children as $child){
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($child->ID).'">'.$child->post_title.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}   
?>
```

edit: made include links as indicated in title

Comment: hello i tried to use your code on my page, but i get empty Array, what do I have to change to make it work ?

Comment: do you have child pages of the current page?